# Convert date from Christian to Buddhist in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date-conversion

I'm using `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')` in a MySQL query.

How can I also convert the date from a "Christian" year to a "Buddhist" year?

Comment: I believe this involves adding 543 years, yes?

Comment: @showdev No,I'm sorry.
I'm a rookie.

Comment: I was just confirming what's involved with the conversion. It's fine to be a rookie :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [may be an oversimplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_calendar#Epochal_date), but if you simply want to add 543 years, you could use:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 543 YEAR),'%Y-%m-%d');
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 543 YEAR),'%Y-%m-%d') |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2558-07-10                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `date_add` that is wrong, when in a year February has 29 days.

Your must convert only year.
You must not use the function `date_add`.

Example:

```
concat( left(dte, 4)+543 , right( dte, 6))
```